# Visual Studio Default Terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

As of the latest visual studio code update they have decided to make changing the default terminal very confusing (at least for me!)

when trying to select default terminal as cmd the window closes and nothing happens.

to be more clear: How do I set the default vs code terminal to cmd instead of powershell?

Comment: "...the window closes and nothing happens." - do you mean the dropdown of terminal profiles? Or the VSCode window, or a different window?

Comment: yes the terminal profile window